# Border with margin-top

Tags: html, css

I would like to make a `div` that has a `margin-top: -110px`, but I want to add a `border-right` on it starting from the top of the `div`, but without the `margin-top: -110px` attribute.

[image]

I know I could use two or more `div`, but it needs to be done with only 1. Can it be done with CSS or I need to use JavaScript?

Comment: You will need two divs for this.

Comment: Unfortunately, this isn't possible with just CSS. You'll need to use two divs. In Javascript, you can programmatically draw another div on top that is clear, with a border, but then again, that's still using two divs.

Comment: I wonder if you couldnt use some hack with the :before and :after selectors... I was never good at those.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this using the CSS pseudo-elements:

```
div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 200px;

    border-top: 100px solid red;

    position:relative;    
    background-color: gray;
}

div:after {
    display: block;
    position:absolute;

    content:" ";

    width: 0;
    height: 100%;

    border-right: 3px solid lime;
    top: 0;
    right:-3px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6W2KP/5/

[image]